# Перенос строк при абсолютном позиционировании

Tags: css, css3

Не могу привести в порядок пункты меню чтобы текст не выходил из зоны `vc_col-sm-3`, а при многострочности нижеследующие сдвигались вниз.

[image]

Дело осложнено тем, что **существующий код нельзя изменять**, можно только добавить правила css.

Поскольку код несколько великоват и тут некорректно работает, выложил на http://www.cssdesk.com/GeKEV (новая версия кода)

Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему.

Comment: странно, зачем позиционировать абсолютом текст...

Comment: @GGO Сам в шоке, но это сделано не мной. Это вордпрессовская премиальная тема и плагины накидали гуана. А теперь я с этим разгребаю, но с позиционированием у меня не очень хорошо складывается.

Comment: это просто жестяк, а не код...

Comment: а зачем там чекбосы? чёт непонятно без них все норм будёт

Comment: @GGO это вообще-то фильтр. Просто не думал, что надо на это обращать внимание

Comment: крч этому фильтру бабахаете .icheckbox_flat-aero {display: none !important}, а тогда .woof label { position: initial !important;} может поможет

Comment: @GGO чекбоксы прятать нельзя. Я понял, что совершил ошибку не указав об этом в вопросе. Сорри.. Исправил вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.woof_list.woof_list_checkbox > li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

.woof_list.woof_list_checkbox .icheckbox_flat-aero {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.woof_list.woof_list_checkbox .woof_checkbox_label  {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  word-break: break-all;
  position: static;
}
```

Comment: Ну вот, оказывается можешь же, когда захочешь :). Зачем же было минусовать и закрывать прошлый вопрос? Похмелье мучало? ;) Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: А вот `word-break: break-all;` лишнее.